# Almost sure convergence of non-rising subalgebras sequence

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm studying almost sure convergence and trying to prove that the following statement is true or false:

> For every non-rising sequence $\sigma$-subalgebras $G\small{n}\subset F$ for every $A \in F$ $P(A|G\small{n}) \xrightarrow{a.s.} P(A|\cap {\tiny n \in N} \space G\small{n})$

I feel that it is true. But how to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an immediate consequence of the backward martingale convergence theorem. Any probability textbook will prove this. Also [see here](https://www.randomservices.org/random/martingales/Backwards.html#:~:text=A%20backwards%20martingale%20is%20a,convergence%20theorem%20for%20ordinary%20martingales.).

Comment: I don't see anything related to almost sure convergence in the article you have provided

Comment: @michaeluskov Look at 6a

Comment: Why if $P(Y\small{t} \to Y\small\infty) = 1$ then $P(A|G\small{n}) \xrightarrow{a.s.} P(A|\cap {\tiny n \in N} \space G\small{n})$?

Comment: Because $Y_t$ is an arbitrary backwards martingale and the sequence of conditional probabilities is a backwards martingale.